# Ошибка initramfs при загрузке

Tags: linux, debian

Случайно выключила с кнопки комп, при включении вылезла эта ошибка initramfs. Что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://losst.ru/kak-vosstanovit-fajlovuyu-sistemu-v-fsck

Comment: Тут будет потеря данных.

Comment: Запустите `fsck -y /dev/sda1`. 
У вас винчестеру приходит конец, бэкапьтесь чаще.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=run+fsck+manually

Comment: Спасибо!!! :) Эта команда помогла:


fsck -y /dev/sda1 ; reboot -f

Comment: Поддержу @AlexanderProkoshev - верхняя часть экрана выглядит так же, когда я с полумёртвых винтов типа `WD Blue` пытаюсь вытащить инфу. Не гарантия, но повод задуматься. Бэкапься и проверь винт с помощью `mhdd`.

Comment: @donRumata, Кабель может быть плохим.

Comment: @0andriy, БП тоже может плохие токи выдавать. Тоже было. В любом случае - повод всё проверить.